# How to get reference to module by string name and call its method by string name?

Tags: python

The modules are already imported in the current module ( no need of dynamic import ), and have an ALIAS name.
The requirement is to get reference to the module by its alias name, and call its function

current module :

```
import libraries.mymaths.products as myproductlib

def call_func(module_name,method_name):
    # module_name = 'myproductlib' , method_name='mult'
    # how to call myproductlib.mult here ?
```

`getattr(MODULE_REF, method_name)` would help me to get reference to method, but how to get reference to module by its alias name ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To get the module, you can use `globals`.  To get the function, use `getattr`:

```
getattr(globals()[module_name], function_name)
```

Importing a module just binds the module object to a name in whatever namespace you import it in.  In the usual case where you import at the top level of the module, this means it creates a global variable.

Answer (score 10):

[BrenBarn's `globals()` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17142143/548792) works with the module name, ALIASESED or not, only if the import is located in *this* module (the one currently running).

If you still want to get hold of the module by its *unaliased name* (e.g. it was imported earlier, from some other module), get it from [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules) with a FQN module name like `"apackage.somemodule"`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import libraries.mymaths.products as myproductlib

>>> globals()["myproductlib"] == sys.modules["libraries.mymaths.products"]
True
```

Comment: While both answers work, I prefer this one because it does not require an `import` of the module (which would appear unused if not used anywhere else).